# Looking for survivalist compound materials

Tags: maps, post-apocalyptic, adventure-writing

I'm running a post-apocalyptic campaign in GURPS 4E, and the PCs are probably going down the path where their arch villain will be the leader of a survivalist group that has some crazy notions and lots of supplies and ammunition in a more or less centralized compound in a rural area.

I've been trying to research anything in the RPG realm that I can repurpose, with no luck. Do you know of anything? I've since expanded to non-RPG (historical, other fictional settings) for maps, descriptions, layouts, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Steve. (Make sure to read our [FAQ]). Can you reframe your title into a question? Are you interested in site plans? The history of such things (check out history.stackexchange.com ) or something else?

Comment: Ever heard of the [Waco siege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waco_siege)?

Answer (score 6):

The website for a National Geographic show called *[Doomsday Preppers](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/doomsday-preppers/)* provides a lot of potentially useful material. The [shelter](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/doomsday-preppers/articles/get-prepped-shelter/) section talks about how a survivalist would select a location for their compound, and other sections talk about security, food supplies, and so on. While I couldn't find any plans, the episode *[Taking from the Haves](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/doomsday-preppers/episodes/taking-from-the-haves/)* looks like it may do a good job of describing the mentality of a survivalist, how one goes about planning a compound, and some of the details of a home that is also a compound.

Update:

Survival compounds are on the rise among the wealthiest of the wealthy. A 2017 *New Yorker* article goes into detail about why, where, and how some surprisingly sophisticated [survival compounds](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/01/30/doomsday-prep-for-the-super-rich) are being created to cater to successful and fearful denizens of Wall Street and Silicon Valley.

A 2017 article in *The Atlantic* about [luxury doomsday bunkers](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2017/03/a-resort-for-the-apocalypse/513869/) provides a map and a floorplan.

One thing that comes through in both of these articles is that this sort of thing is on the rise, and those building and buying survival bunkers believe it's possible to ride out the chaos in luxury.

It's easy to imagine a scenario in which a multimillionaire loses control of his bunker to someone better suited to the end of the world. Perhaps his security chief takes over, or a cunning outsider connives his way in and assumes control.

Answer (score 5):

Some links:

- [Memorializing the Mount Carmel Center](http://www.stormbound.org/waco.html) This includes pictures of a model and maps of the besieged buildings in Waco at the time of the siege. It also includes a lot of information about what has happened since.
- [A secure compound, off grid](http://www.survivalblog.com/2012/05/a-secure-compound-off-grid-by-steve-r.html) Description of everything needed in a compound.
- [Go Underground](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/engineering/architecture/4325649) 6 ready-to-buy now bomb shelters

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that you should ask this I just finished this short book [A Distant Eden](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1475049838). As a novel it only virtue is that is short. However as a guide to the survivalist mentality and especially technical details it pretty good. The kindle version is only .99 and you can use the Kindle of PC to read it on your PC if you don't have the Kindle Version.